# How can I get access to the variables stored in this Javascript Array (vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, model

I am working on a little exercise with the Javascript Vue.js Framework.
I cut the following code to show my problem. I have two variables with no value in the data part. I try to edit the two variables in a method.

I stored two number values in a array called "counter".

I stored the two variables (a and b) from the data part in an array called "values" (with the "this") before.

Then I use two for loops to edit them. But I can't get access to the variables a and b, when they are stored in the array "values". I think my problem is the Array "values". If i change the values[i]  in the last for-loop in "this.a", it works. But not if I want to get access with the variables stored in the array.

I think it is a JavaScript problem but I don't know, how I can solve it. I already looked up some similar questions in stack Overflow but I can't transfer the solutions to my case.

```js
// Vue.js Model-Part

data: {
   a = '';
   b = '';
}

//A snippet out of the method-part
var one = 13;
var two = 14;

counter = [one, two];
values = [this.a, this.b];

for(var i = 0; i < counter.length-1; i ++){
    for(var position = 0; position < counter[i]; position ++){
        values[i] += "*";
};
```

Comment: Hello @LDP97 could you be more cleared to explain what you want to acheive with vuejs. Pls

Comment: I don't think you are accessing the data object using `this` keyword. When you console.log `this.a`, what do you get?

Comment: @Birante I have to built a little rich-client. I know my example is not that good. I tried to show my problem very quick. I am sorry if my code is not understandable.

Comment: @Syntiara My original code looks not like my given example. But with the this keyword I get the access to the variable in the data part.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a` and `b` are strings their values copied in the `values` array. So doing

```
for(var position = 0; position < counter[i]; position ++){
        values[i] += "*";
```

just changing copies of their values in the **values** array. So you either should modify **this.a** and **this.b** directly or you can capture these variable into a function that changes their values directly itself.

```
var functionToChangeAandB = (val1, val2) => {
  this.a = val1
  this.b = val2
}

functionToChangeAandB('one', 'two')
```